# How to update vue-meta on route/url change?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vue-meta

The meta data on my website is not updating when the route changes. The route itself has a `watch` on it which updates the view fine, but the `metaInfo()` from `vue-meta` is not keeping up. The `<script>` section of my code looks like this:

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: "Product",
        watch: {
            '$route.params.ProductID': {
                deep: true,
                immediate: true,
                handler() {
                    this.getProduct(); // calls getProduct() on route change. Can I also call metaInfo() from here somehow?
                }
            }
        },
        metaInfo() {
            return {
            title: this.Product.ProductTitle,
            meta: [
                {
                    name: 'description', content: this.Product.ProductTitle
                }
            ]
        }
        },
        computed: {
            Product() {
                return this.$store.getters.getProduct
            }
        }, mounted() {
            if (this.Product == null || !this.Product.length) {
                this.getProduct();
            }
        }, methods: {
            getProduct() {
                return this.$store.dispatch('loadProduct', {ProductID: this.$route.params.ProductID})

            } 
        }
    }
</script>
```

What is happening is that when I change my route and go from `/product/123` to `/product/124`, the `metaInfo()` still shows the meta data for `/product/123`. If I hit refresh, then the `metaInfo()` updates and shows the correct data for `/product/124`.

I need the `watch` to trigger an update of `metaInfo()` but don't know how to do it. I can't find this information in the docs anywhere. Please help?

Comment: To anyone else coming here, I have stopped using vue-meta and went for https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vueuse/head instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reactive, use variables outside return statements.

```js
metaInfo() {
    const title = this.Product.ProductTitle;

    return {
        title: title,
        meta: [
            {
                name: 'description', content: title
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/guide/caveats.html#reactive-variables-in-template-functions